# How can I use jQuery Terminal and Bootstrap/CSS to change the style and create a top-left terminal?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the input and output of the jQuery Terminal to be entirely within the top-left of a screen that's been split with Bootstrap, though I'm not sure how to do that. Ideally, it'd be something similar to Codecademy page (something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbRG4.jpg) except the terminal is on the top left).

I thought adding the following terminal code inside the div left-side block would work. But, by doing so, the terminal box is instead outside and below the leftside class.

Any advice or suggestions? Generally, I just have no idea how I can use Bootstrap/CSS to manipulate jQuery terminals.

```js
var body = $('body').terminal(
  function(command) {
    this.echo(command);
  }, {
    greetings: 'Test',
    name: 'Test',
  }
);

terminal_print = function(str) {
  body.echo(str);
};
```

```css
.leftside,
.rightside {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .leftside,
  .rightside {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}

.leftside {
  background: black;
}

.rightside {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery.terminal/js/jquery.terminal.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/jquery.terminal/css/jquery.terminal.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col-md-6 g-0">
      <div class="leftside"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 g-0">
      <div class="rightside d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        This page is intentionally blank
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've specified the body element as the target. Why not use your element? (It doesn't matter where the code sits--you're specifying the target element in the first line.)

I've converted your identity classes to IDs and updated your terminal function name for clarity.

```js
var terminal = $('#leftside').terminal(
  function(command) {
    this.echo(command);
  }, {
    greetings: 'Test',
    name: 'Test',
  }
);

terminal_print = function(str) {
  terminal.echo(str);
};
```

```css
#leftside,
#rightside {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  #leftside,
  #rightside {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}

#leftside {
  background: black;
  color: #ddd;
}

#rightside {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery.terminal/js/jquery.terminal.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/jquery.terminal/css/jquery.terminal.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col-md-6 g-0">
      <div id="leftside"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 g-0">
      <div id="rightside" class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        This page is intentionally blank
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```